# Why am I getting different ApiControllers between projects even though they appear to be in the same dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a testing utilities class I'm working on extracting some commonly used code in to. I tried pulling out some code setting the controller ActionContext, and it caused an error in the new class, saying that there is no ActionContext in ApiController. So I started digging.

The project I'm pulling code from is a Web API project referencing System.Web.Http version4.0.0.0, File Version 4.0.20710.0 and using the class System.Web.Http.ApiController.

The project I'm consolidating the code into is ALSO referencing System.Web.Http version 4.0.0.0 4.0.20710.0.

In both places the code looks exactly like this (simplified to help me find the issue):

```
    public static void SetUpFields(System.Web.Http.ApiController controller)
    {
        controller.Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
        controller.ActionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(); // Issue happens on this line
    }
```

In the new library project it says cannot resolve ActionContext. If go to declaration in both places they are very obviously different objects. I just can't figure out WHY they are pointing to different objects. They are both referencing the exact same version of System.Web.Http and should be hitting the same version of ApiController.

Comment: When you say "very obviously different objects", what do you mean? Different definitions (properties and methods). Do you mean different state and contexts? Could you give examples of a few differences (show above/update your question).

Comment: Looking at the code they just don't line up at all. The one referenced by the library is much smaller and has less properties available (most notable, ActionContext, which is the one I'm trying to set). The one referenced by the Web Api project is 592 lines with 22 dependencies. The one referenced by the new utility project is only 349 lines with 13 dependencies. They have the same class signature and namespace (public abstract class ApiController : IHttpController, IDisposable) and definately have many similarities, but in the end they are very different classes.